# Passing complex types from SignalR hub to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

From the hub i need to call a function on the client that is expecting an undefined number of object-type parameters like this

```
{name: 'John', age: 20}, {key: 'Smith', id: 5, ...} ...etc
```

but i obviously can't write the arguments like that on the server side. I could just send all the data as a single string value and parse it on the client but i feel there has to be a better way to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use JSON.net and send a `JObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an array of objects to a function on the client.  Have this function then split that array up into parameters to pass into your existing function by using 'apply':

```
function wrapperFunctionToCallFromServer(arrayOfObjectParameters) {
  actualFunctionYouWantToCall.apply(this, arrayOfObjectParameters);
}
```